# How to convert a list of strings to a single string in Unity (C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to C#, and apologies for the noob question - I'm trying to convert a list of strings to a single string so I can use it with WWWForm's POST function.

If I have a list of strings (e.g. `kidIds = ["a#123", "b#123"]`), how do I easily convert it to a single string (`"a#123, b#123"`)? In Javascript, I would simply do `kidIds.join(",")`, but I'm not sure how to do it in C#.

I tried doing `kidIds.ToArray().ToString()`, but it's not really giving me what I want. I could loop through the entire list using a for loop, but I was wondering if there's a simpler one liner I could use?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is basically the same thing as JavaScript's `join()`

[String.Join Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thank you, this worked perfectly! Will accept answer after the 5 mins have elapsed.

Answer (score 7):

Since you are new to C# I would like to tell you that, you were trying to convert a list of strings to a single string. No it is not a list of string but it is a array of string. List of strings would be initalize like

```
List<string> SomeName = new List<string>();
```

Where as your one is declared as array. Now you can Join the Array of strings into one string as same as Javascript like

```
string SomeString = String.Join(",", kidIds);
```

The [`string.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx) method combines many strings into one. It receives two arguments: an array (or IEnumerable) and a separator string.

You can also create one string out of the String array using `+` that would concatenate the strings like

```
string smstr = String.Empty;
for(int i=0; i<kidIds.Length; i++)
{
    smstr = smstr + kidIds[i];
    //or
    smstr += kidIds[i]
}
```

You can also choose StringBuilder to create one string out of array of strings since StringBuilder.Append() method is much better than using the + operator like

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0;i<kidIds.Length;i++)
{
    sb.Append(kidIds[i]);
}
```

But StringBuilder is good when the concatenations are less than 1000, String.Join() is even more efficient than StringBuilder.

Answer (score 4):

Use `String.Join(',', kidIds);`

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tk0xe5h0(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Thanks a lot, I knew there was a oneliner for that. Except I had to use `string.Join(",", kidIds)` since it expected a `string` not a `char` as first parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you can try the function concat, like

```
String str = "";

str = kidIds[0] + kidIds[1];
```

or

```
str = str.concat(kidIds[0], kidIds[0]);
```

or

```
for(int i=0;i<length;i++)
{
    str += kidIds[i];
}
```

I think i would help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using following code...

```
 string[] kidIds = { "a#123", "b#123" };

        String str = "";

        foreach (var kidId in kidIds)
        {
            str += kidId + ",";
        }

        str = str.Remove(str.Length - 1,1); // this line use for remove last comma
```

thanks...